# Where to set the theme for an Eclipse-based application?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created an Eclipse plugin application which is having one `*.product` file. For running this application I have to right-click on the application then run/debug as Eclipse application then my app will open and its having same theme as my Eclipse workspace.

The requirement is to set an Eclipse theme like [Moonrise](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme) for this Eclipse plugin application not for workspace, so I am not getting where to save or change the theme for this plugin.

Any help whould be appreciate. Below is the image for the product file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point and the **product property *cssTheme*** in the **`plugin.xml`** file where your product is specified (in your case `com.testlid.main.ui/plugin.xml`):

```xml
<extension id="product"
           point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product name="%product.name"
           application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"
           description="%product.description">
    <!-- ... -->
    <property name="cssTheme"
              value="com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui.standalone"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </product>
</extension>
```

See also:

- [An example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/com.vogella.vde/blob/4a118589b2f9f342be62c360b7acf9f7a3dff6b9/com.vogella.vde/plugin.xml#L52)
- [*Eclipse 4 CSS Styling - Tutorial*](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html)

Comment: Thank you howlger for your help, but after putting css theme property also theme is not getting applied , I thougth we need to download theme locally in some format then applied it how property valuecom.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui.standalone will load the theme .

Comment: Of course, the Moonrise feature must be part of the product and it only works with a new workspace (because the selected theme is stored in the `.metadata` folder). Have you [tried the example of Lars as a product](https://github.com/vogellacompany/com.vogella.vde)? If I understood your question correctly, this is a demo of how it works. For me this worked with the [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jeeeyuls-eclipse-themes) for an RCP application, but I haven't tried it with the Moonrise theme yet.

Comment: I am following the same example (Eclipse 4 CSS Styling - Tutorial) there it is metion to use org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.IThemeEngine; to change theme at run time I have added org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme plugin also still in import statment IThemeEngine is not importing , any ideas ??

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are: to set the default theme, to support the Moonrise theme in addition or to programmatically switch to the Moonrise theme. Your screenshot shows a plug-in-based product configuration. Maybe a feature-based product configuration would be easier in your case.

Comment: howlger , my requirment is to set theme for my eclipse plugin product as I came from web application development background eclipse plugin develpment is pretty new to me , so if you help me out it would be great ! so the question is how to download the moonrise theme and then  I will set property   `com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui.standalone `then after running my application , theme should set

Comment: What do you mean by _"plugin product"_? Either you create a plug-in which can be installed in an existing Eclipse IDE (via a so-called feature) or you create your own whole Eclipse-based IDE/application (so-called RCP application via the product file like the one in your screenshot). There are recommended tutorials for both [_feature_](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#exercise-create-a-feature-for-your-plug-in) and [_RCP application_](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#exercise-creating-an-eclipse-rcp-application)